# React Native Linking.getInitialURL() not get full URL

Tags: android, react-native

Why react native Linkin.getInitialURL() won't get the full URL ?

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const bla = Linking.getInitialURL()
    console.log(bla)
  }, [])
```

here the result of console.log

[image]

I test in cmd like this

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://curious-dev.web.app/verify/?mode=action&oobCode=23423432"
```

i need the rest of the URL, it must be like this "https://curious-dev.web.app/verify/?mode=action&oobCode=23423432"

but what i got from getInitialURL is "https://curious-dev.web.app/verify/?mode=action"
where is the rest of URL?, is there have characters limit or what ?

your help will save me.
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example will work fine in real device, but when testing with `adb shell` you should escape ampersand in URLs.

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://curious-dev.web.app/verify/?mode=action\&oobCode=23423432"
```

Check this [discussion](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29630) for more details.

And `getInitialURL` returns a Promise that resolves to the URL, so use `async/await` to get the URL.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getUrlAsync = async () => {
      const initialUrl = await Linking.getInitialURL();
      console.log(initialUrl);
    };
    getUrlAsync();
  }, []);
```

Check out more examples in Linking API [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking).